# localstorage works well.. no need display in same page.. i want display this data into next html page in with div ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

localstorage works well.. no need display in same page.. i want display this data into next html page in with div ?

try i display in next html page with in div#id decent manner. whenever i want call same data and display any html page?

```
<form id="logForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="project" value="Project Name">
    <input type="number" name="hours" value="Hours" class="shortField">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="Date" class="shortField">
    <input type="submit" value="Log Time">
</form>

<ul id="theLog">
    <li>Loading&hellip;</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) {
        alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
    } else {
        getAllItems(); //load the items

        $("#logForm").submit(function(){
            var newDate = new Date();
            var itemId = newDate.getTime();
            var values = new Array();
            var project = $("input[name='project']").val();
            var hours = $("input[name='hours']").val();
            var date = $("input[name='date']").val();

            //strip html tags
            project = project.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
            values.push(project);
            values.push(hours);
            values.push(date);

            if (project != "" && hours != "" && date != "") {
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem(itemId, values.join(';'));
                } catch (e) {
                    if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                        alert('Quota exceeded!');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("All fields are required.");
            }
        });
    }
});

function getAllItems() {
    var timeLog = ""; //the variable that will hold our html
    var i = 0;
    var logLength = localStorage.length-1; //how many items are in the database starting with zero

    //now we are going to loop through each item in the database
    for (i = 0; i <= logLength; i++) {
        //lets setup some variables for the key and values
        var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
        values = values.split(";"); //create an array of the values
        var project = values[0];
        var hours = values[1];
        var date = values[2];

        //now that we have the item, lets add it as a list item
        timeLog += '<li><strong>'+project+'</strong>: '+hours+' hours - '+date+'</li>';
    }

    //if there were no items in the database
    if (timeLog == "")
        timeLog = '<li class="empty">Log Currently Empty</li>';

    $("#theLog").html(timeLog); //update the ul with the list items
}
</script>
```

Comment: and i want simply it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying - but if you want to use localstorage in another page, it should just plain work. Can you show us the code of the second page that attempts to read in localstorage values and display them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have stored your data into local storage then you can access this data from any page opened in the same browser ( because local storage belongs to your browser , actually all data is stored in browser space and you can't access data store in one browser from any other browser). Thanks